# git pull not merge my changes

Tags: git

I have a problem with git pull, my problem is the following:

I make a:

```
git add .

git commit -m "Message"

git pull origin <remote>
```

and get this:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

but not merge my local files with the changes that are in the remote repository!.

How can I do for force it ?

my

```
git status
```

get nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Note: before of make pull, I did a push -f origin  of a git reset --hard SHA1_HASH (IN THE REMOTE REPOSITORY)

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to merge your local changes with git pull, you have to commit them (locally) first. Did you do it ?

Comment: Yes I did a git add . and a git commit -m "mensake"

Comment: Did your commit go through? What does your `git status` say?

Comment: And if you want the changes to be present in the remote repository, you have to do a git push after the merge.

Comment: my     git status dice     nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: I make a `git add .` then `git commit -m "mensaje"` then `git pull origin <remote>` but not merge my local files with the files that are in my remote repository my `git status` get  *nothing to commit (working directory clean)*

Comment: So you need to first push your changes into your remote repo and then pull request it from your origin. I don't believe you can pull directly form your local repo.

Comment: noMAD-> I think what you say is correct, but I don't understand how can do, You have a example?

Comment: @Marcelo : add a '@' before the name of noMad in your comment if you want him to be notified (and answer).

Comment: @noMAD-> I think what you say is correct, but I don't understand how can do, You have a example? –

Comment: @Marcelo what do you want to do? you want to push your local changes to the remote github repo?

Comment: @uDaY No, I want merge my local files with the files that are in my remote repository but I make a pull and not make nothing

Comment: @Marcelo, you shouldn't do `pull` for that you have to do `push` to reflect your local changes in remote repo.

Comment: @uDaY I have all working fine in my remote repository so, now I want update my local files in me local repository but the "PULL" say that it is all update and is lie because between my remote repository and my local repository there are differencies!

Comment: @Marcelo, which repo is ahead the local one or the remote one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you create a repo on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository)
Once you do that (say you named it `MyRepo`), branch off your `origin` and work on that branch. When you need to push stuff back to your origin, what you do is:

```
1. git add <your changes>
2. git commit -m "" <your commit message)
3. git push <your local repo> <Link to MyRepo>
```

If you have RSA key configured with github you don't need to enter your credentials. Then you pull request from origin.